# Spending the night at Mumbai airport

Tags: safety, sleeping, mumbai, bom

I will arrive to Bombay airport at 11:00 pm and my flight is the next day at 6:00 pm. Can i spend that time in the airport waiting room? Is there any problem for safety?

Comment: What safety problems are you thinking about?

Answer (score 2):

The to-go guide for these question is http://www.sleepinginairports.net/asia/bombay.htm this website. It would seem from these reviews there shouldn't be a problem except it might be uncomfortable even for an airport.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily spend that time at the airport. There are multiple lounges, and some are even open 24/7.

If you really want to spend your time relaxed; try the [pranaam lounge](http://www.csia.in/atcsia/pranaam-lounge.aspx) - a 6 hour pass will cost between 45 and 55 USD.

Your credit card may also grant you access to the [loyalty lounge](http://www.csia.in/atcsia/loyalty-lounges.aspx) at Terminal 2.